# Enter credentials in standalone PyQGIS script

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, postgresql, standalone

I'm developing standalone script using PyQGIS. I would like to access to layers in QGIS project but IDE returns an error.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from qgis.core import QgsDataSourceUri
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(path_to_qgs, True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
path_to_qgis_project = r'path....'
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read(path_to_qgis_project)
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
print(layers)
QgsProject.instance().write()
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

Above syntax is working on the shapefile but crashed when I put PostGIS layers to project.
'Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)'

Every time when I'm opening *.qgz file I need to type in username and password. I don't want to store credentials in QGIS project but maybe there is a way to pass credentials programmatically?

Do you know how to do pass credentials in standalone script?

Comment: How did it crash? Did you get an error message? What does your script load? How do you load the layers?

Comment: Hi, i added missing lines to the original post. All PostGIS layers are alredy in QGIS project.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/authentication.html

Comment: I'm doing something wrong. I set master password, etc. but QGIS still wants credentials whenever I open *.qgz project. Do you have examplirary script which i could use? PS. I'm using QGIS 3.1.